# CanCan, nested resources and using methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

In my new project, I have a resource Bet which other users can only read if they are the owners of the bet or friends of him. The main problem comes when I want to define abilities for the index action. In an index action, the block does not get executed, so I guess it's not an option.

Let's illustrate it. If I wanted only the owner to be able to index the bets, this would be enough:

```
can :read, Bet, :user => { :id => user.id }
```

But I need the acceptable ids to be a range, one defined by all the friends of the user. Something like:

```
if (bet.user == user) || (bet.user.friends.include? user)
    can :read, Bet
end
```

But this is not correct CanCan syntax.

I guess that a lot of people has had problems with CanCan and nested resources, but I still haven't seen any answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

In your Bet model, create a method:

```
def is_accessible_by? (user)
    owner = self.user
    owner == user || owner.friends.include?(user)
end
```

Now in ability.rb, set your CanCan permission:

```
can :read, Bet { |bet| bet.is_accessible_by?(user) }
```

**EDIT**

As you point out, since index actions don't have an instance of the object, the block above won't get executed.

However, it sounds like what you are trying to do - list the bets owned by the user or their friends - should not be handled using CanCan or permissions.  I would create a function in my User model:

```
def bet_listings
    friend_bets = friends.inject([]){ |bets, friend| bets<<friend.bets; bets }
    self.bets + friend_bets
end
```

Then in your index action:
`@bets = user.bet_listings`

Comment: It does not work. The conditions in an ability blocks are not used in actions like index.

Comment: You are correct , I didn't read your question closely :(
I'll give one more suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Just now I have found a solution, but I don't like it much. It's about creating a custom action and defining abilities for it. For example...

In the controller:

```
def index
  authorize! :index_bets, @user
end
```

In ability.rb:

```
can :index_bets, User do |friend|
  user == friend || user.friends.include?(friend)
end
```

It works, but I don't feel great about using it. Isn't out there anything more elegant?